# JSON web scraping query encounters 'forbidden' error

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I encounter an error "403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:" when running the following code.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/map/gettrackjson/shipid:5630138/stdate:2022-05-18%2015:07/endate:2022-05-19%2015:07/trackorigin:livetrack"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()

print(response.json())
```

On the other hand, replacing with following url works:

```
url = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/vesselDetails/latestPosition/shipid:5630138"
```

Would anyone know why the first url doesn't work and if there's a way to make it work? The original page is at https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/home/centerx:79.3/centery:6.9/zoom:10.